# Javascript style changes break Selenium(GEB) test

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, geb, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am currently working on a pretty simple input form with various input elements, such as selects, texts and radiobuttons. The form is validated upon post and if not validated successfully the form is displayed again with erroneous fields highlighted. The highlight is achieved by adding a class `has-error` and appending a div with an error message. Upon correcting the error - say checking one of the radio-buttons in a group - the `onChange` event is captured and it removes the `has-error` class and the div:

```
if ($(obj).parents('div.has-error')) {
    $(obj).parents('div.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
    $(obj).parents('div.has-error').find('div.help-block').remove();
}
```

It works exactly as intended when performed by a "real" user. However when the exact same thing is performed by a Selenium (GEB) test, the radiobutton isn't checked. For a short while it has the "focus" dotted line as if it tabbed through the element.[image]

Hence the test fails since the radiobutton is never checked. If I remove the above mentioned javascript it works just fine... And likewise if I remove just one of the two statements....

The test is written with GEB and uses "form-control-shortcuts" to set the value of the fields by name, like:

```
class FormModule extends Module {
    static base = { $('form#personform') }
    static content = {
        personskoen { "person.koen"().module(RadioButtons) }
    }
}

class OpretPersonPage extends Page {
    static url = "person/opret"
    static at = { title.contains("person.opret.titel") }

    static content = {
        form { module FormModule }
    }
}
```

And the value is set in the test like this:

```
def () {
    given:
        at OpretPersonPage
    when: 
        page.form.persoenskoen = "KVINDE"
    then: 
        page.form.persoenskoen == "KVINDE"
}
```

I am completely stuck and have no further ideas to test. I really hope you guys have some!

I am using:

```
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:2.52.0
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:2.52.0
org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:2.52.0
```

Comment: This: `$(obj).parents('div.has-error')` will **always** be "truthy" because `.parents()` always returns a jQuery object. You have to test the `.length` of jQuery objects to check whether they're empty or not.

Comment: As true as that is, it unfortnuately doesn't fix the issue. Which also is a bit alarming, since this mean that the code is always run - wheter there are errors or not. This in turn leads me to think it is somewhat because of changes to the dom/page that screws with selenium... It is ONLY radiobuttons that has this problem :(